The Poincaré-Bertrand Formula for the Heaviside Step Function
The Poincaré-Bertrand formula gives for singular integrals over a smooth curve $\Gamma$ and a function $\phi(t,t_0) = \alpha(t)\beta(t_0)$, where $\alpha\in L^p, \beta\in L^q$ and $q=p/(p-1)$, the following identity:
$\int_{\Gamma}dt\frac{1}{t-t_0}\int_{\Gamma}dt_1 \frac{\phi(t,t_1)}{t_1 -t} = -\pi^2f(t_0, t_0) + \int_{\Gamma}dt_1\int_{\Gamma}dt\frac{\phi(t,t_1))}{(t-t_0)(t_1-t)}$
My question is: If $\Gamma$ is just the real axis, can the Poincaré-Bertrand formula be used in a distributional sense for $\phi(t, t_0) = \theta(t)\theta(-t_0)f(t_0)$, where $\theta$ is the heaviside step function and $f$ a function from a suitable $L^p$-space?
I am motivated by an expression on the form
$H\left[ \theta_{+}H[\theta_{-}f] \right](t)$,
where $H$ is the Hilbert transform, and $\theta_{\pm}$ denotes the heaviside step function for positive and negative arguments, respectively.
